# C++ operators overloaded as a consequence ('+', '+=')

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

When I overload, lets say, the '+' operator for a class in C++

```
MyClass MyClass::operator+(MyClass _c){
    //code here
}
```

Does it automatically apply to the '+=' operator? Does the compiler automatically substitute that for its longer conuterpart (a+=b <--> a=a+b)? Or is it a runtime operator function?

Comment: It does not. At least MSVC++ compiler seems to think its not valid.

Comment: Writing an `operator+=` in terms of `operator+` sounds very expensive - create a temporary LHS from this, add RHS, then assign the result temporary to this. It would be a bit simpler the other way round - write `operator+=` and implement `operator+` in terms of it.

Comment: Also, conventionally, an `operator+()` changes neither of its operands (i.e. `a+b` changes neither `a` nor `b`).   This can be expressed by use of `const`.

Comment: In C++, you typically write the += operator in all it's glory, and then write: `foo operator +(foo lhs, const foo& rhs) { return lhs+= rhs; }`.  That is a free-standing function, not a member function, and note that `lhs` is passed by *value*.  (It's important not to make it a member function, because otherwise `aBar + aFoo` (where `bar` implicitly converts to `foo`) won't compile;

Comment: I didint mean to ask if it automatically overloaded it with the same function,  but if the compliler automatically replaced a+=b with a = a + b; that would be really simple, and should that be the case, the answer would be YES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It doesn't. You need to overload those as well.