# C++ smart macros - regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, macros

**Introduction** (dont read if you dont want, this is just for background)
I am creating an API for C++ so that it has python-similar functionalities, without loosing its essence. I have successfully developed an automatic generic exception handling system (I asked how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841770/generic-exception-handling-in-c), and @MacZamborg told me how it works, so I started dismantling everything from scratch). Like I said, I managed to overload quite a lot of things so that the will automatically throw the according exception (which inherits from std::exception). The only one I had trouble with, was the ZERO_DIVISION exception, because it seems you cant overload operators just for ints, that is, one of the arguments, needs to be an object. So I created the Object Num, which uses an union to store any numeric data available) -> this means, I have to overload each operator 11 times, so I wanted to avoid the need to overload the **X=** operators. (Also asked something about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906402/c-operators-overloaded-as-a-consequence)).

---

**Question**

Is there a way in any IDE, to make smart macros? what is a smart macro, you may ask, well, lets pretend there is a new language called C+++, which implements smart macros > a smart macro should behave like this >

```
#define "regEx" "Literal replacement"
```

In practice:

```
#define '([^\d ]?\w+\s*)\+=' '$groups[0] = $groups[0] + '
```

With **([^\d ]?\w+\s*)** being the only element in the groups array (The syntax comes from python's regEx, I may have some mistakes, but the idea is the same). 
That part of the regEx, will match any valid variable name (including reserved keywords [not derirable, but we get rid of them with the **\+=**]), that is, any word that starts with anything but a space or a digit, contains any character, and ends with spaces (0 or more). After that, it looks for the **+=** operator, and if matched, it repaces the whole match with **'$groups[0] = $groups[0] + '**, that is, whatever was found on the only group (denoted by parenthesis), 'space' '=' 'space' 'what was found again' 'space' '+'

What all of this is addressed to, is to avoid having to overload the **+=** operator (read intro if you may)

Comment: Why do you capitalize the G in "*reGex*"?

Comment: So that its clear that its a compound word, for those who dont know what it is,

Comment: What do you think it stands for? "reular Gexpression"?

Comment: @melpomene man, you are so right, cant believe I didint see it before, sorry and thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like all you want is a custom preprocessor that understands and expands "smart macros". You can implement that e.g. as a python script that transforms text files.

As for how you can integrate this into your build process, that depends on what software you're using.

For example, with `make` you can do something like the following:

```
%.cpp: %.cppx
        mysmartpp $< > $@
```

Now if you have a source file called `foo.cppx`, `make` will automatically invoke `mysmartpp foo.cppx > foo.cpp` to create `foo.cpp` from it. (This assumes you've written a `mysmartpp` script that understands the "smart macro" syntax).